# All possible binary label generation (not binary byte generation) and/or save numbers using commas

Tags: python, format, python-itertools

I want to generate a binary label systematically and I hope I can generate a three or four labels later, if my first analysis worked well.

Here is the code to make the binary label combinations:
`lst = sorted([i for i in itertools.product([1, 0], repeat=len(my_data))], key=sum)`

The above code worked well if the samples to add labels were small like N = 5. However, if N is greater than 20 or so, I do get an error assuming due to a memory error.

Thus, I had to change my strategy and although this is not an ideal method, I found the other way to go from SO.
[Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set)

However, I then faced on a different problem.
The data format I want to save for future use is like 1,1,1,1 or 0,1,0,1, not 1110 or 0101.

I guess I can modify the pseudo labels to be a comma separated by using awk after saved but it should be of great if I can convert the format as comma separated in python before saving for the convenience.

Your suggestions for both itertools.product and comma separation are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can trivially add commas between all the characters of a string.  `comma_separated = ','.join(list(binary_str))`.

Comment: This gave me '1111', '0101' ... to 1111, 0101 ... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851134/generate-all-binary-strings-of-length-n-with-k-bits-set) but anyway, thank you for your help. I do keep in mind for future use.

Comment: That's because you were using my suggestion on a list of strings.  It was intended to be used on each individual string in the list - I thought my naming convention of `binary_str` would be clear.  Try `[','.join(list(binary_str)) for binary_str in result]`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding itatools.product, I figured out and solved by myself referring by those website.

1. [Why do I get a MemoryError with itertools.product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695422/why-do-i-get-a-memoryerror-with-itertools-product)
2. https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-itertools-product/
3. [Create dataframe from itertools product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712500/create-dataframe-from-itertools-product)
4. [Writing to csv file with itertools.product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67508441/writing-to-csv-file-with-itertools-product)

In my case, I simply removed the sort and the code became
`lst = itertools.product([1, 0], repeat=len(my_data)`, which went well. Also, I was able to manage the sorting stuff in the later step. Thank you.